# Azure App Service integrate to accessible only via vnet gateway VPN

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

Im Trying to Create a web application that can only accessible via vnet or only network connected to vnet VPN.

I setup vnet and create a Gateway that has point-to-site configured.
I setup the Web Service and on the network side i allow the gateway to access the Web.
Then i connect to vpn on my local machine but still not able to access the web app.

what i did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please check when you create webapp . Under basic configuration **sku and Size**  is *not Standard S1* because its not working on standard S1.

Check its if its Standard S1 then its not working.
[image]

Steps to create.

1. Create Vnet and under vnet go to subnet. create two more sub net, first subnet and second Gateway subnet.

[image]

2. Create App service plan. make sourer not select **Standard S1**

[image]

[image]

3. Create web app.

[image]

4. At this time its access to publicly.

[image]

[image]

5. Under left hand side panel select Networking.

[image]

6. Open private endpoint connections.

[image]

[image]

after approved click go to app service and click on URL. at this time its not accessible to publicly.

[image]

[image]

7. Create a VM, under networking section select virtual network those created.

[image]

8. Go to resource and connect to this VM.

[image]

11. Connect and open web application. its run fine on VM.

[image]

More information read these document [Use Azure Private Endpoints to Restrict Public Access to WebApps](https://www.varonis.com/blog/securing-access-azure-webapps) by Neeraj Kumar.

Comment: Hi that's works on my end. the next thing that I want to do is. from my local machine,. so my step is.

1. create vnet gateway. 
2. setup point to site VPN
3. from app service networking Allow the Gateway.
4. from my local machine connect to VPN using point-to-site (I was able to connect)
5. access the App Service.

im to connect to VPN Point-to-site but im still getting forbidden error even thou I set the VNet gateway to allow to access the site.

Comment: @merdekatest, check connection properly connected or not.